# How to rewrite this code block?

Tags: c#, refactoring

I have a class having around 40 properties (I have no say about this, it is as per the spec). All properties have custom "set" methods.

There is one a little bit complicated validation which I have to impose on all the "set" methods. I have already separated the validation into a separate method, lets call it

`CommonValidate(string PropertyName, string PropertyValue)`.

As of now I am calling this validation method from each individual "set" methods, as you can see below:

```
    public string Property1
    {
        set 
        { 
           this.field1 = value; 
           CommonValidate(Property1, this.field1);
        }
     }

    public DateTime Property2
    {
        set 
        { 
           this.field2 = value.ToString("ddMMyy");; 
           CommonValidate(Property2, this.field2);
        }
     }

     public string Property3
    {
        set 
        { 
           this.field3 = value; 
           CommonValidate(Property3, this.field3);
        }
     }
```

This way I have just pasted CommonValidate method calling in all 40 "set" methods.
I find this being very ineffective, imagine if there is a change request for the number of arguments in the CommonValidate method.

Is there any other way I could change this into better mode?

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This is not a codereview question.

Comment: passing only "this" to CommonValidate?

Comment: Thi sproblem is closely related to the implementation of `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Research it and you will find that there are tricks using Reflection but no perfect solutions.

Comment: Try using AOP. For example: http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Introduction-to-AOP-With-Castle.ashx

Comment: @wudzik Sorry, I thought something specific in C# may be applicable for this case.

Comment: @Giwrgos, Its something just come top of my head for quick sample snippet. I get what you are trying to imply.

Comment: It will obviously depend on how your requirements will change in the future and that can be impossible to predict. If your requirements are only likely to change for some properties then at that time you could add an overridden CommonValidate method for specific properties or add optional parameters. The other route, as others like @Henk have suggested, is to go down the Reflection route which adds it's own complexities as well as performance considerations.

Comment: What about implementing a dynamic class that has a custom setter? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee461504.aspx  I dnn't usually reach straight for dynamics...but here it could drastically simplify things...You'd keep everything in an underlying Dictionary...

Answer (score 1):

You could use reflection to have a function which you pass in the name of the property and new value.  It does the validation, then performs the normal set with the value.  Reflection is not efficient in regards to speed but is great for reusing code.  Do some diagnostics to ensure time lost is within your acceptable bounds.

```
void ValidateAndSet(string propName, object newValue){
    foreach(var prop in propsClass.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => p.Name == propName))
    {
        if(CommonValidate(prop, newValue))
            prop.GetSetMethod().Invoke(propsClass, new object[] { newValue});
        return; // Only one anyways
    }
    Logger.Log("Failed to find the property '{0}' to set '{1}'", propName, newValue);
}
```

propsClass is the class object that the properties are in. Can do this within the class or pass it in the function as another parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Someone already mentioned Dynamic classes, I'm not familiar with them, but brief reading makes them sound rather attractive for your problem.

However, if you don't go that route, one thing I would change is the use of strings in `CommonValidate`, and instead use `System.Linq.Expression`.

I'd rewrite it to look something like:

```
static void CommonValidate<T>(Expression<Func<MyClass, T>> propertySelector, T newValue) //replace MyClass with name of current class
{
    MemberExpression memberExpression = propertySelector.Body as MemberExpression;
    if (memberExpression == null)
        throw new ArgumentException("propertySelector")

    string propertyName = MemberExpression.Member.Name;

    //validation code, e.g.

    CommonValidate(propertyName, newValue.ToString())
}
```

Then the setters would then look like

```
public string Property1
{
    set 
    { 
       this.field1 = value; 
       CommonValidate(c => c.Property1, value);
    }
 }
```

The advantage of this is that if you change the name of a property on your class, it becomes a compile-time error not to change the `CommonValidate` call.  If you do go this route, you should use something similar to set up your validation: I'm assuming you've got a constructor somewhere populating a `Dictionary<string, Func<string, bool>` - use code similar to that in the new `CommonValidate` above to get the property name keys instead.